# How to remove space in $location.search() ?

Tags: angularjs

I have    `$location.search('event', data);`  but problem is that i get in url something like this :

```
?event=arsenal%20fc%20
```

and i want to remove this spaces to get : arsenalfc

Comment: `$location.search('event', data.replace(/ /g, ''));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the data on the spaces and rejoin it with no spaces.

`data = data.split(' ').join('');`

**Update**

Based on the conversation in the comments you might be better of replacing with a hyphen. This will give you the nice looking urls you desire whilst giving you the opportunity to re-replace them with spaces at the other end.

Remember to trim your search string first so that you don't get a trailing hyphen:

`data.trim().split(' ').join('-')`

Comment: what if i want to check data again i will not get result am i right?

Comment: What do you mean by "check data"? If you don't want to overwrite the original variable you can put the newly reduced value in a new var.

Comment: i want also to use this part of code  if($location.search().event){...} but problem is if i have arsenal fc and it remove space and i get arsenalfc i cant find it anymore...do u know what i mean?

Comment: Not really, no. Why are you removing the space in the first place if you want to search based on the string with spaces?

Comment: because when i remove space i get clean url :) without %20 :)

Comment: Ok so if this is about having nicer looking urls, you could replace the space with a hyphen `-` and then replace the hyphen with a space at the other end.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84155/discussion-between-none-and-jamie-dixon).

Answer (score 1):

Just replace the spaces with nothing:

```
$location.search('event', data.replace(/ /g, ''))
```

Comment: Doing a replace this way will only replace the first instance of a space. All other spaces will be left intact.

Comment: True, I've now changed it to replace all spaces.